# Difference between signal and error for compiler (sbcl 1.2.4)

Tags: compilation, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I got strange error from SBCL compiler, so may be someone can explain to me what is going on there. For information the package uses optima and drakma. I really tried to minify posted code, but this amount required to understand the problem.

```
(defun signal-vk-error (code)
  (error ;; <--- HERE IS THING
    (case code
      (100 'parse-error)
      (otherwise 'error))))

(defmacro match-with-error (response matcher)
  `(match ,response
         ((alist (:ERROR . code))
          (signal-vk-error code))
         ,matcher))

(defun api-call-response (resp)
  (match-with-error
    resp
    ((alist (:RESPONSE . data)) data)))
```

Compiling this file I got:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   don't know how to dump CODE (default MAKE-LOAD-FORM method called).
Unhandled TYPE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                  {1002BF6F03}>:
  The value NIL is not of type (AND ATOM (NOT NULL)).
```

So there it looks like sbcl (1.2.4) can't create binary representation, but I can't underestand why.

If I just change ERROR to SIGNAL in signal-vk-error - everyhing compiles, loads and works as expected. I can also just load file in slime and eval is, it will work without errors and warnings.

So, the question is, what is wrong with `error`? What is major difference between `error` and `signal`?

**UPDATE 1:** Interesting observation, if I remove signal-vk-error function, and just put this code inside macro defenition it will compile ok.

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks to @RainerJoswig, declaring `signal-vk-error` not to be inlined fixes the problem. [Reported to SBCL team](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1378476), looks like they doing some optimization, which brokes compilation in this case.

Comment: Where is the code variable coming from? Use macroexpand to see what the macro expands into.

Comment: I tried. optima:match just binds variable code to value of specified place in alist, if there is any. Macroexpansion not giving any clue really (don't want to post long code here). Anyway, `error` called inside function defenition, if there is some problem with variables, why changing `error` to `signal` helps? It shouldn't.

Comment: if it does not matter, you should be able to simplify the code and still see the error.

Comment: I simplified some of it (removed my own conditinons, removed unneded branches and so), it seems to me like optima issue, may be I should contact them on github.

Comment: Remove drakma... Since MATCH seems to be a macro, you really need to see what it does and what it creates.

Comment: is the `ALIST` symbol in the correct package? `optima.extra`? the three uses of `alist` should be really equivalent to `optima.extra:alist`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, I simplified more. See edited question.

Yes, i required optima.extra of course. The funny thing - it works with signal, and fails with error. If there was no optima.extra required, it must fail in any case. I'll see what match doing, but it's a lot of code to understand. U just can't figure out how `error` called even not in macro defenition can have such effect, and why `signal` don't.

Comment: What does require mean? Did you *use* the package optima.extra in your package?

Comment: @RainerJoswig, yes, i mean use of course. Here is package defenition:

`(defpackage #:test-dump-error
  (:use #:cl #:optima #:optima.extra))` And even if I didn't - how changing `error` to `signal` may help? It shouldn't.

Comment: Could be a problem of SBCL 1.2.4. In an earlier version it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. Will report issue to SBCL now.

Comment: If you declare the call to error to not be inlined, it works.

Comment: @RainerJoswig, thanks. Declaring it notinline works. So i think there is some optimization SBCL trying to do, I'll report it, and see what they'll say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it came out, there is a problem in compiler, in fact two of them, one of which is allegedly a feature. Anyone interested can read the conversation between one of SBCL hackers and the author of optima [in bugtracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1378476).

For now this fixed in optima side by not revealing pattern object during macroexpasion, [commit d7ec93d0df4920b9a7b4a492e7aadf52480f437c](https://github.com/m2ym/optima/commit/d7ec93d0df4920b9a7b4a492e7aadf52480f437c)

Answer (score 1):

Smallest way to reproduce the problem:

```
(defun signal-vk-error ()
  (error 'error))

(defun api-call-response ()
  (optima:match 1
    ((not 2)
     (signal-vk-error))))
```

If I macroexpand or walk the `match` form, the problem disappears.

The following also makes the problem to disappear.

```
(declaim (notinline error))
```

Comment: Thanks. Tt's simpler. I changed code in bugreport.Also checked with CCL - compiles without declaration.